# Range search in Multi_dimensional R-Trees

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, spatial-index, r-tree

I am trying to implement `R-Tree in C++`.
While implementing Range Queries, I find that I have to check for the intersection of a point (with a given range), with a multi-dimensional hyper rectangle.

Any idea how this could be done? For `2D case` I know, but how to do it for `N-Dimensional Case`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a morton curve treat the co-ordinates as a binary and interleave it. Then treat the number as base-4. Then search it from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as in the 2d case.

just use a loop.

Comment: @Anony-mouse:How does it look like? Maybe a grey code?

Comment: No, *much* much easier. See: you are talking about *rectangles*. Not hilbert curved.

Comment: @Anony-Mouse:I talk about boxes.

Comment: The intersection of axis aligned boxes is ... a box. Seriously, you only need "min" and "max".